# Choosing the Row that has the most complete information

Tags: r

Let's say I have rows like this:

```
    First, Last, Address, Address 2, Email, Custom1, Custom2, Custom3
1    A, B, C, D, E@E.com,1,2,3
2    A,  , C, D, E@E.com,1,2,
3     ,  ,  ,  , E@E.com,1, ,
```

What I would like to to do is create a function that pulls that row which is most complete and I'm wondering if there are any packages or pre-existing methods (recommendations, even) for doing this. In the example above, I would like to to have a function that chooses row 1.

I can't use complete.cases() or na.omit() because in many circumstances the cases are not complete and contain at least one NA. I've tried combining unique() with a number of specific pulls... but I'm not having much luck automating this manipulation task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to character and the count row-wise how many non-emptys you have:

```
R> Lines <- "
+ First, Last, Address, Address 2, Email, Custom1, Custom2, Custom3
+  A, B, C, D, E@E.com,1,2,3
+  A,  , C, D, E@E.com,1,2,
+   ,  ,  ,  , E@E.com,1, ,
+ "
R> 
R> con <- textConnection(Lines)
R> df <- read.table(con, header=TRUE, sep=",")
R> close(con)
R> 
R> m <- as.matrix(df)  # now all char
R> 
R> counts <- apply(m, 1, function(r) { r <- gsub("^ $", "", r); 
+                                      sum(na.omit(r) != "") } )
R> 
R> df[which.max(counts), ]   # pick row of maximum
  First Last Address Address.2    Email Custom1 Custom2 Custom3
1     A    B       C         D  E@E.com       1       2       3
R>
```

Comment: This could work really well, I just have to figure out how to extend it for multiple email addresses. In my example, I provided just one subset for one email address but in my actual file I have thousands of unique email addresses each with their own subset of rows.

Comment: Then the email addresses become a factor and you use `aggregate`, `by`, `*ply`, ... to sweep over the unique values of the factor, applying the solution shown here to each such chunk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the facts that "" is less than either any letter or any number, so just use `sum (x >"" , na.rm=TRUE)` in an apply framework:

```
> apply(tst, 1, function(x) sum(x > "", na.rm=TRUE))
[1] 8 7 6
> idx <- apply(tst, 1, function(x) sum(x > "", na.rm=TRUE))
> tst[which.max(idx),]
   First Last Address Address.2    Email Custom1 Custom2 Custom3
1 1    A    B       C         D  E@E.com       1       2       3
```

Comment: A similar but simpler approach to what Dirk has done above. Thanks!

Comment: It's the same, really. I just started showing how I got the `data.frame`, made it a matrix etc pp -- the key is to sweep across rows and run sums of the comparisons.  And that is the same.

Comment: @Brandon: In answer to your follow-up question below Dirk's answer: You could "apply" this function within unique collections of lines having the same email address by using tapply or aggregate. I'm sure there are power-plyr and power-data.table users that could get you something either more compact or faster depending on which of those you went with.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are already some working solutions I post mine. It is similar (in using `apply` and `sum`) but uses regular expressions (via `grepl`) for achieving it. So you can try to use any pattern you want. The used 'trick' is that logical values can be summed:

```
x <- structure(list(First = c("A", "A", ""), Last = c("B", "  ", "  "
), Address = c("C", "C", "  "), Address.2 = c("D", "D", "  "), 
    Email = c(" E@E.com", " E@E.com", " E@E.com"), Custom1 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), Custom2 = c(2L, 2L, NA), Custom3 = c(3L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("First", 
"Last", "Address", "Address.2", "Email", "Custom1", "Custom2", 
"Custom3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

mostComplete <- function(x) {
    tmp <- apply(x,1,grepl, pattern = "[[:alnum:]]")
    return(which.max(apply(tmp,2,sum)))
}

mostComplete(x)

[1] 1
```

PS: Give the youth a chance...